# Kubernetes nginx ingress with wild card domain does not get SSL certificate

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a Kubernetes based setup using microk8s. I have an ingress defined with wildcard domain. I also have a cert manager to get certificate from LetsEncrypt.

I am able to see LetsEncrypt has issued the certificate. However, the nginx does not use the certificate issued by LetsEncrypt. Instead, it uses the default self signed certificate.

Why is it not associating the certificate to the domain?

```
root@test:~# kubectl get ingress test-ingress -o yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: test-cluster-issuer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 1024m
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-10T00:11:09Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: test-ingress-class
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: web
            port:
              name: ui-port
        path: /
        pathType: Exact
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.domain.com
    secretName: k8s-tls-secret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.x.x.x

----------
root@test:~# kubectl describe certificate k8s-tls-secret
Name:         k8s-tls-secret
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-03-10T00:11:09Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by:
        f:ownerReferences:
          .:
          k:{"uid":"28715da3-0cb9-4a04-a58b-f483211c6512"}:
            .:
            f:apiVersion:
            f:blockOwnerDeletion:
            f:controller:
            f:kind:
            f:name:
            f:uid:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:dnsNames:
        f:issuerRef:
          .:
          f:group:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:secretName:
        f:usages:
    Manager:      cert-manager-ingress-shim
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2023-03-10T00:11:09Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
        f:revision:
    Manager:      cert-manager-certificates-issuing
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2023-03-10T00:14:32Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:notAfter:
        f:notBefore:
        f:renewalTime:
    Manager:    cert-manager-certificates-readiness
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2023-03-10T00:14:32Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           networking.k8s.io/v1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  test-ingress
    UID:                   28715da3-0cb9-4a04-a58b-f483211c6512
  Resource Version:        6865
  Self Link:               /apis/cert-manager.io/v1/namespaces/default/certificates/infra-tls-secret
  UID:                     6723b898-d797-4ae9-814d-9e3e6e67fefb
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    test.domain.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       test-cluster-issuer
  Secret Name:  k8s-tls-secret
  Usages:
    digital signature
    key encipherment
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-03-10T00:14:32Z
    Message:               Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                Ready
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
  Not After:               2023-06-07T23:14:30Z
  Not Before:              2023-03-09T23:14:31Z
  Renewal Time:            2023-05-08T23:14:30Z
  Revision:                1
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                       Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                       -------
  Normal  Issuing    39m   cert-manager-certificates-trigger          Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  39m   cert-manager-certificates-key-manager      Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "k8s-tls-secret-7p5lx"
  Normal  Requested  39m   cert-manager-certificates-request-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "k8s-tls-secret-pwz8c"
  Normal  Issuing    35m   cert-manager-certificates-issuing          The certificate has been successfully issued
```

Comment: Where is the wildcard domain setup? No wildcard is shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ingress, tls is trying to find a secretName: `k8s-tls-secret`. Did you create it? For example:
`kubectl create secret tls k8s-tls-secret --key mycert.key --cert mycert.crt`

Comment: Yes, its created.

Comment: Did you find the root cause? I'm facing the same issue